# max_stack_depth not changed even stack changed in limits.conf

Tags: postgresql, linux, ubuntu, postgresql-9.5

The attempt of making changes to max_stack_depth using `select set_config('max_stack_depth', '512MB', false);` because of the error shown in postgresql log:

```
DETAIL:  "max_stack_depth" must not exceed 7680kB.
HINT:  Increase the platform's stack depth limit via "ulimit -s" or local equivalent.
```

actually, the below line exists in limits.conf. Have tried updating postgresql process using `prlimit` and even reboot the server(OS: Ubuntu). It still reports the same error.

```
*         soft stack   524288
```

if switch to the user postgres and verify the stack size with `ulimit -s` it is already set to 512MB.

This shows there is no `ulimit -s` to change the stack size under /etc.

```
$ sudo grep -r ulimit /etc/*
/etc/init.d/lxd:        ulimit -n 65536
/etc/vmware-tools/vm-support:runcmd "/tmp/ulimit-a.txt" ulimit -a
```

Not sure why postgresql still not seeing this change?

Comment: Perhaps your start-up script is doing something the lower the limit again.  Can you start the PostgreSQL server manually from the same shell in which you checked `ulimit -s` and see if the problme persists?

Comment: Yeah. If switching to user postgresl and start the pg manually then it works! But it still confuses me even start-up script has changed it during boot process, but after switching to the user postgres, the limit is takes effect only after user login. So what's the right approach to set stack size ulimit for postgresql on Linux?

Comment: I don't know.  I think you might get more help over in serverfault or askubuntu.  It seems like a question more about the OS than about the database.  Are you using PostgreSQL as installed from their repository and with their start-up scripts?

Comment: PostgreSQL is installed from its offical repo by using apt-get as suggested from the doc on postgresql.org.

Answer (score 2):

This solution works on Fedora Linux, but should work on Ubuntu as well.  The issue is, that in addition to replacing initd, systemd aims to take over security functions that were traditionally handled by things like `/etc/security/limits.conf`.  (There are other areas where it interferes as well).  When systemd starts PostgreSQL, it ignores `/etc/security/limits.conf`, and applies its own default limits.  To change them, do the following:

```
mkdir /etc/systemd/system/postgresql.service.d
cat > /etc/systemd/system/postgresql.service.d/postgresql.conf << XYZZY
[Unit]
Description=PostgreSQL database server
After=network.target

[Service]
LimitSTACK=infinity
XYZZY

systemctl daemon-reload
```

This method also has the added benefit that will not interfere with default changes to service unit files, should they be updated upstream, but will permanently maintain your settings override.  This [helpful post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345595/how-to-set-ulimits-on-service-with-systemd) lists the other limits that may be set through systemd configuration.

I should note that, at first, I tried to set the limit to 131072, but when I attempted to start PostgreSQL, I got this error:

```
DETAIL:  "max_stack_depth" must not exceed -384kB.
```

Changing it to infinity allowed PostgreSQL to start.